# How to get index of repeating elements in an array..?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to find index of elements stored in an array,
some elements are coming repeatedly, when I am trying to get index of those elements its giving the index of first element always.
For Eg:

```
int[] arr = {3,5,6,7,2,3,11,14 };
        int index = Array.IndexOf(arr, 3);
        Console.WriteLine(index);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

when I want to get the index of 3 as 5, its still giving 0.
I cannot skip elements in my logic, I have to check each element every time in my program.
PLease help if some can.

Regards.

Comment: why you want this indexes

Comment: @AmitSingh Does that really matter?

Comment: I need to send the index of array in my program according to array element size, I dont want to swap elements, I just want to send index of array elements, first I have to send the index of smallest element of my array, then index of greater and so on..
I dont want swapping.
please help.

Answer (score 1):

There is an overload of the `IndexOf` array that takes a starting index. Use the index of the first item to find the next:

```
int[] arr = {3,5,6,7,2,3,11,14 };

int index = Array.IndexOf(arr, 3);
Console.WriteLine(index);

int index2 = Array.IndexOf(arr, 3, index + 1);
Console.WriteLine(index2);

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I need to send the index of array in my program according to array element size, I dont want to swap elements, I just want to send index of array elements, first I have to send the index of smallest element of my array, then index of greater and so on.. I dont want swapping. please help.

Comment: @user2345759: Where do you get swapping from? The code doesn't do that. The code simply finds the first instance of `3`, then uses the index of that instance to find the next instance of `3`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are searching for a solution indipendent by the number of time the searched term is present in the array. In this case you need a loop where you perform your work on the current item found

```
int[] arr = {3,5,6,7,2,3,11,14 };
int index = -1;
while((index = Array.IndexOf(arr, 3, index + 1)) != -1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(index);
}
```

The [Array.IndexOf(array, object, startindex)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b2fz03t.aspx) overload will work exactly as you expected

Comment: I need to send the index of array in my program according to array element size, I dont want to swap elements, I just want to send index of array elements, first I have to send the index of smallest element of my array, then index of greater and so on.. I dont want swapping. please help.

Comment: Well, for the above code, when the search term is 3 the index variable will be 0 at the first loop and 5 on the second one. What do you mean 'to send index of array elements'?

Comment: I want to send index of elements,
int[] arr = {3,5,6,7,2,3,11,14 };
for this array, I am trying to return..
4,0,5,1,2,3,6,7

Answer (score 0):

You could use `LINQ` and the `Select(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, Int32, TResult>)` - here is the [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx).

```
var indexes = arr.Select((i, index) => new { Number = i, Index = index }).Where(x => x.Number == 3).Select(x => x.Index).ToArray();
```

Then to get the last index (if that is what you want) use `LastOrDefault()`, as apose to `ToArrray`.

Answer (score 0):

**Try Below:**

```
int[] arrRepaetInd = new int[arr.Length];
int j=0,cnt=0;
for(int i=0;i<arr.Length;i++)
{
  j++;
  if(arr[i]==arr[i+1]
  {
    cnt++;
    arrRepaetInd[cnt]=arr[i];
    Console.WriteLine(arrRepaetInd[cnt]);
  }
}
```

arrRepaetInd array is having indexes of repeated elements.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use Select plus a filter.

```
public int[] IndexesOf<T>(T[] Values, T find) {
    return Values.Select((i,index) => new { index = index, value = i})
                 .Where(x => x.value == find)
                 .Select(x => x.index)
                 .ToArray();
}
```

or even as an extension method

```
public static class MyExtensions {
    public static int[] IndexesOf<T>(this T[] Values, T find) {
        return Values.Select((i,index) => new { index = index, value = i})
                     .Where(x => x.value == find)
                     .Select(x => x.index)
                     .ToArray();
    }
}
```

Then you can do

```
var indexes = arr.IndexesOf(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a class that implements IEnumerable and returns the indices you want:

```
public class Traverse<T> : IEnumerable<int>
{
    T[] _list;
    T _value;

    public Traverse(T[] list, T value)
    {
        this._list = list;
        this._value = value; 
    }

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _list.Length; i++)
            if (_list[i].Equals(_value))
                yield return i;
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
    int[] arr = { 3, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 11, 14 };

    foreach (var index in new Traverse<int>(arr, 3))
        Console.WriteLine(index.ToString());
```

output:
0
5